# How document.getelementsbyname() is providing the value? whereas when checking into inspect element I found value as empty

Tags: javascript, html

Value obtained from console by using `document.getelementsbyname()`
[image]

Inspecting the element and value field is empty
[image]

Comment: The value is updated in the shadow DOM of the input (at least in chrome), it's not visible on the HTML.

Comment: The `value` attribute only contains the initial default value, not the current value.

Answer (score 1):

The value attribute shows the **default** value for an input.

The value property deals with the **current** value.

Something must have changed the value before you tried to read it.